# How to delete empty sheets that have a header row from excel workbook in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete all empty sheets from a workbook, and these sheets have headers, so they are not completely empty. Just row 2 and on will be empty and I need to delete these sheets.

I currently have this:

```
def DeleteEmptyColumnsAndRows(filename):
    import pandas as pd
    import pathlib
    full_path = filename
    df = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name=None)

    # engine can be openpyxl if we need .xlsx ext
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_loc, engine='xlwt') 
    for key in df:
        sheet = df[key].dropna(how="all").dropna(1, how="all")
        sheet.to_excel(writer, key, index=False, header=False)
    writer.save()
```

This works fine for completely empty sheets but my sheets have headers. Any idea how I can manipulate this to work how I need it to?

Thanks in advance, any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the solution to delete all sheets from a workbook where the 1st row (the header row) is the only row with any data in it:

```
def DeleteEmptyColumnsAndRows(filename):
    import pandas as pd
    full_path = filename
    df_with_header = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name=None)
    df_without_header = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=0, sheet_name=None)


    # engine can be openpyxl if we need .xlsx ext
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_loc, engine='xlwt') 
    for key in df_with_header:
        if not df_without_header[key].empty:
            print(df_with_header[key])
            sheet = df_with_header[key].dropna(how="all").dropna(1, how="all")
            sheet.to_excel(writer, key, index=False, header=False)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

sheet = workbookname.Worksheets('Sheet_name')

sheet.Delete()

This code will delete the specified sheet from workbook(win32com)

Comment: It has to be dynamic unfortunately. I can't specify the sheet name. It needs to go through the whole workbook and delete any sheets that are empty (other than the first row/header)